# Adding specific value in a string stored at an array in program memory of pic using C

Tags: c, pic

I want to put a string in the program memory of a pic18f.
Inside this string I need specific values at some positions.

E.G.

```
rom const unsigned char date_const_array[]="Date:";
```

will place the string `Date:` inside program memory.

What I want is to insert to position 3 of the array the value 15 at compile time.
If the array was in ram I could do:

```
date_const_array[3]=15;
```

inside main function. But since I do not want this array to be altered and I value my ram I want it to be placed inside rom.

How can I do it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You could embed 15 right in the string using escape sequences: `"Dat\017:"` (017 is an octal constant: 1*8<sup>1</sup>+7*8<sup>0</sup>=15).

Comment: And you do need the leading 0 digit of 017 so that the compiler knows it is an octal constant because it is expecting three octal digits.

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edsza5ck.aspx for a description of Octal and Hexadecimal character specifications.

Comment: @RichardChambers Correct. Hex digits are supported as well (`\x0F` would be the 15).

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I think this will be success

`rom const unsigned char date_const_array[]=__DATE__;`   // Many compilers uses this way.